# selenium rc unable to click on a link

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, selenium, gallio

I'm facing a kinda weird problem today. Selenium appears to click on a link in one test case, but, ignores the same link in the subsequent case. This happens with any permutation-combination of test cases. Whichever case run 2nd, fail due to the above problem. can anyone suggest a solution for this?? I've tried selenium.click and selenium.clickat. combination of mouseup+mousedown doesn't work even at the first go. selenium.fireevent also doesn't seem to make any difference.

Really stuck at this. Can anyone please help????

Thanks and Regards,
Vamyip

Comment: Could you paste your tests? Looks like the first test changes some state in the system, so the second test doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for prompt reply. Its a simple statement selenium.click("link=mylink"). The weird thing is that selenium identifies the link to be present, but, simply doesn't click it. I fear that I wont be able to paste the code of test since I'm bound by company policies. Please let me know if the given statement doesn't help. I'll try to get some meaningful equivalent of my test script here.Thanks

Comment: what is the click on the link supposed to do? Does the link have a href target? Is it a real uri or a javascript: fragment? Or else does the link only have the onclick event?

Comment: The link has a real URL. I mean, no javascript or Onclick events.

Comment: Does Selenium give you any output? I think it is unable to find the link in the second test, so it can be caused by many different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Does the link open a new window? If so, I would try the selectWindow("myMainWindow") command to be sure the proper page has the focus.

Comment: Nopes, the target opens in the same window. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Causes may be

a) the element has not shown in the page before that you had executed the case

sugg- wait for that element   waitFor("link=mylink") and then call selenium.click("link=mylink")

b)there may be spelling error or locator not given properly